# Words derived from ‘veni’ and ‘vidi’ of Latin

Tags: etymology

Veni, vidi, vici (Classical Latin: [ˈweːniː ˈwiːdiː ˈwiːkiː];  "I came; I saw; I conquered") is a Latin phrase popularly attributed to Julius Caesar.
[Veni, vidi, vici - Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Veni,_vidi,_vici)

As for ‘vici’, there’s words of ‘victory’, ‘victor’, ‘ originated from.
[*weik- | Origin and meaning of root *weik- by Online Etymology Dictionary](https://www.etymonline.com/word/*weik-?ref=etymonline_crossreference)

Are there words derived from ‘veni’ and ‘vidi’?

Comment: I think this is probably more appropriate for english.stackexchange.com ("a question and answer site for linguists, etymologists, and serious English language enthusiasts") than for ELL.

Comment: Video, I see in Latin. Present tense. Normally, words derive from nouns or adjectives. Not from past tenses of verbs.....Those words from Julius Caesar are the  past tense of Latin verbs. This is a beginner's question and think it is ok here.

Comment: Questions need to have an answer that can be ranked objectively by the community as "correct" or "good". Questions that ask for lists of things aren't a good fit for the Stack Exchange format.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lots and lots of words:

Veni (basic parts: venio, venire, veni, ventum): intervene, convene, convent, convention, convenient, venue, invent, prevent, convenant (https://www.etymonline.com/word/*gwa-)

Vidi (video, videre, vidi, visum): video, vision, visual, television, vista, view, preview, interview, provide, improvise, evidence, envy, visa (https://www.etymonline.com/word/*weid-)

Vici (vinco, vincere, vici, victum): invincible, victory, convince, evince, convict, conviction, eviction, Vincent, province, vanquish (https://www.etymonline.com/word/*weik-)

I built these lists myself, then realized you can refer to the sources I've appended from the Online Etymological Dictionary, after which I added a couple more examples.

Comment: The roots are not the past tense.

Comment: I wasn't assuming the OP only wanted words derived from the specific past-tense forms used in the motto. The OP's own examples aren't--they come from the root "vict-" associated with the participle.

Comment: I said that words deriving from Latin and Greek do not come from past tenses at all. Ergo, the question is incorrectly posed. Venire gives us that list you posted: and not "veni". Venire is an infinitive verb. The Julius Caesar thing in terms of words from Latin is a red herring. That's all.

Comment: If you are able to get a hold of one derived word independently, you can look it up, and click the linked Indo-European root. For example, https://www.etymonline.com/word/venue has a link to "*gwa-", https://www.etymonline.com/word/*gwa-. Not everything derived from *gwa- came through Latin "veni" or "ventum", (example: "basis"), but you can then inspect the items in the list individually to see which did come through the intermediate root you're wondering about.